ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API is not working after deployment to the server. There are multiple error in Eventviewer
Getting the below error after the deployment. The port in IIS web server is 7090, but it tries to bind to 5000 which is used by another website. Not sure why it is not using the 7090.
Error #1 in event viewer:

Application '/LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT/WebAPI' with physical root
'D:....\WebAPI\ProjectName_API' failed to start process with
commandline '"dotnet" .\ProjectName.WebAPI.dll' at stage
'PostStartCheck', ErrorCode = '0x8027025a', assigned port 47359,
retryCounter '1'.

Error in Eventviewer

The error is  Application '/LM/W3SVC/7/ROOT/APIProjectName' with physical root 'D:..\APIProject\APIProjectName' failed to start
process with commandline '"dotnet" .\APIProjectName.WebAPI.dll' with
multiple retries. Failed to bind to port '38628'. First 30KB
characters of captured stdout and stderr logs from multiple retries:
fail: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[11]
Hosting failed to start
System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use.
---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
is normally permitted.
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10048): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally
permitted.
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError
error, Boolean disconnectOnFailure, String callerName)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportOptions.CreateDefaultBoundListenSocket(EndPoint
endpoint)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint
endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint
endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig
endpointConfig, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass28_01.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.DefaultAddressStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(ListenOptions[] listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, Func2 useHttps,
CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken
cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token) at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable1
services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean
abortOnFirstException, List1 exceptions, Func3 operation) Unhandled
exception. System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address
http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use.  --->
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Only one usage
of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally
permitted.  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10048): Only one
usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is
normally permitted.    at
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError
error, Boolean disconnectOnFailure, String callerName)    at
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportOptions.CreateDefaultBoundListenSocket(EndPoint
endpoint)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint
endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint
endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig
endpointConfig, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass28_01.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.DefaultAddressStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(ListenOptions[] listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, Func2 useHttps,
CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken
cancellationToken)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable1
services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean
abortOnFirstException, List1 exceptions, Func3 operation)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken
cancellationToken)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
host, CancellationToken token)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
host, CancellationToken token)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost
host)    at Program.$(String[] args) in
D:\Jenkins\Service\workspace\Supplier Portal Rewrite\Supplier Portal
Dev TMS
Web\JCP.SC.Portal.TMSWeb\JCP.SC.Portal.TMSWeb.ExcelUpload.WebAPI\Program.cs:line
70 fail: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[11]
Hosting failed to start
System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use.
---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
is normally permitted.
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10048): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally
permitted.
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError
error, Boolean disconnectOnFailure, String callerName)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportOptions.CreateDefaultBoundListenSocket(EndPoint
endpoint)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint
endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint
endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig
endpointConfig, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass28_01.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.DefaultAddressStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(ListenOptions[] listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, Func2 useHttps,
CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken
cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token) at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable1
services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean
abortOnFirstException, List1 exceptions, Func3 operation) Unhandled
exception. System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address
http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use.  --->
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Only one usage
of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally
permitted.  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10048): Only one
usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is
normally permitted.    at
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError
error, Boolean disconnectOnFailure, String callerName)    at
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportOptions.CreateDefaultBoundListenSocket(EndPoint
endpoint)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint
endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint
endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig
endpointConfig, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass28_01.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.DefaultAddressStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(ListenOptions[] listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, Func2 useHttps,
CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken
cancellationToken)    at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable1
services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean
abortOnFirstException, List1 exceptions, Func3 operation)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken
cancellationToken)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
host, CancellationToken token)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
host, CancellationToken token)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost
host)    at Program.$(String[] args) in D:..\Program.cs:line 70

Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddAutofac();

// other project related lines

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var corsURL = config["CORS_AuthPolicyURL"].Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("PortalCORSPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins(corsURL)
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowAnyOrigin();
}));

builder.WebHost.UseIISIntegration();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

app.Run();

Log.Information("Web API started....");


Could you please tell me which mode you have used when hosting inside the IIS? Inprocess or outofprocess? You could find it inside the web.config.

Hi Brando Zhang, tried with both Inprocess and OutOfProcess both did not work out for me. Currently set it as OutOfProcess.

Port 5000 is already in use.. go to your launchSettings and change the application URL port to something else.

@Charles, LaunchSettings.json will not be there once the pacakge is created, right? launchSettings is for development.

Check your " web.config " there might be some settings or modules that manipulates the hosting settings.

Port is already in use error is related to;
builder.WebHost.UseIISIntegration(); is the trick .... using hosting.json may used to fix. or .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:XXXXX/") in code etc.

Do you run multiple websites under a single apppool in your IIS? If I remember, there can only be one ASP.NET Core application in any given AppPool.

For post-deployment try appsettings.json.

Tried with all the options, did not solve the issue. I had to downgrade to 3.1 framework to make it work.

@SoftwareDveloper , yes multiple websites under a single apppool. however, after separated isn't solve the issue

See if this link helps: https://www.sudshekhar.com/blog/understanding-createbuilder-method-in-aspnetcore#webapplicationbuilder-constructor. "It is inside the ConfigureWebDefaults() method that the server capabilities like using Kestrel, adding Routing and using IIS and IIS Integration capabilities is added to the builder instance."  Do you by any chance have an ASPNETCORE environment variable that is set to port 5000 in your appsettings.json or web.config file?
